# How to position and animate subviews within a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

A `UIViewControler` contains a `UIScrollView` which contains three different pages. On startup the center page is shown with a couple of other views representing two columns of content. These content views are subviews of the ScrollView to be able to move freely between the different pages.

If the user scrolls to the left page some of the content views (the green ones in the mockup) should move to this pages as well (animated) while other views which have not been visible before move in (e.g. the green circle at the bottom). The progress of the animation / movement should be controlled by the scroll position / progress.

If the users scrolls back to the center everything is shows as in the start. When scrolled to the right the other views (red) move to the right page (animated) and other views become visible.

**How can this be solved?**

Of course it would be possible to use `scrollViewDidScroll:` to detect ScrollView changes, calculate the offset and move the views by updating their constraints. **But this would be an absolute nightmare.**

The views do not move linear but change there relative position to each other, etc. Doing this by changing some constraint constants does not work, does it?

**So how to implement such view movements and how to animate them?**

It would be perfect if I could define one layout/constraint set for the start position, one layout for the left page and one layout for the right page and the iOS SDK somehow animates the transitions between these layouts.

This could be done by switching between different constraints sets within a `UIView` animation block, but this would only allow to completely animate from "layout cente" to "layout left" for instance. But in this case the animation should be controlled by the scrolling: If the left page is scroll 50% into its final position the content views should be 50% between their center layout and left layout as well.

**Is this somehow possible?**

[image]

**Edit:**

The red boxes in the center view of the last image should not be there. The boxes moved to the right page.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to approach this. One would be what you are describing (interpolation between two states, driven by scrolling offset). Another approach would be custom [interactive transitions between separate controllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/animation_and_haptics/view_controller_transitions). Finally, since this is a really common pattern (often used for onboarding), you could study/use [some open source projects](https://github.com/onmyway133/fantastic-ios-animation/blob/master/Animation/onboarding.md) that already provide a solution.

Comment: Also, another thing that you could try exploring is to have a keyframe animation between two sets of positions/sizes (based on your constraint sets) and then _pause_ the animation and control its time offset by scrolling.

Comment: Thanks @Alladinian, But transitions between different view controllers will not work, since in my case everything is within the same view controller (even within the same parent view). Interpolating between the states will also not work because I the start and end state would be defined be totally different costraints, e.g. Start = View1 left of View2 and End = View1 below View3... How should I switch between these stats and even *pause* between them to scroll the animation by scrolling?